# i need to generate ansible-playbook using jinja2 with csv file in ansible

Tags: csv, ansible, jinja2, grouping

i need to create jinja templates to generate ansible playbook for that i need to read datas from csv file

csv file is similar to below(file name ansi.csv)

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
aa01,ansi,directory,yes
aa02,jinj,directory,yes
aa01,play,direvtory,yes
aa02,tem,directory,yes
```

and my playbook to generate template is

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    csvfile: "{{ lookup('file', 'csv_files/ansi.csv')}}"
  tasks:
  - name: generate template
    template:
       src: template.j2
       dest: playbook.yml
```

and i have created template like bellow

```
---
{% for item in csvfile.split("\n") %}
{% if loop.index != 1 %}
{%   set list = item.split(",") %}
- name: 'make directory'
  hosts: {{ list[0]|trim()}}
  become: {{ list[3]}}
  tasks:
  - name: {{ list[1] }}
    file:
      path: {{list[1]}}
      state: {{ list[2] }}
{%  endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

out put playbook i'm getting is something simler to bellow

```
---
- name: 'make directory'
  hosts: aa01
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: ansi
    file:
      path: ansi
      state: directory
- name: make directory
  hosts: aa02
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: jinj
    file:
      path: jinj
      state: directory
- name: make directory
  hosts: aa01
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: play
    file:
      path: play
      state: directory
- name: make directory
  hosts: aa01
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: tem
    file:
      path: tem
      state: directory
```

but need to get playbook like bellow

```
---
- name: 'make directory'
  hosts: aa01
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: ansi
    file:
      path: ansi
      state: directory

  - name: play
    file:
      path: play
      state: directory

- name: make directory
  hosts: aa02
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: jinj
    file:
      path: jinj
      state: directory

  - name: tem
    file:
      path: tem
      state: directory
```

in above playbook my expectation is to group by 1st column and only i have to repeat tasks section(if hosts are same), can some one help me to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first read all the csv data in a list of dict and then sort them based on attribute `aaa`. Finally, some more changes in the template should do the job. Below is the change:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: read csv
    read_csv:
      path: csv_files/ansi.csv
      delimiter: ','
    register: csvfile

  - name: generate template
    template:
       src: template.j2
       dest: playbook.yml
```

*template.j2*

```
---
{% set ns = namespace(hvar = "") %}
{% for item in (csvfile.list | sort(attribute='aaa')) %}
{% if ns.hvar != (item.aaa | trim()) %}
- name: 'make directory'
  hosts: {{ (item.aaa | trim()) }}
  become: {{ item.ddd }}
  tasks:
{% endif %}
{% set ns.hvar = item.aaa %}
  - name: {{ item.bbb }}
    file:
      path: {{ item.bbb }}
      state: {{ item.ccc }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you @Moon. Your answer was helful.