# Need to substitute values from a CSV to Ansible template (with for loop)

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

My sample CSV file `cat sample.csv`:

```
ms-1,svc-1
ms-2,svc-2
```

Need to create a configuration file that looks like below:

```yaml
- names:
  - ms-1
  - svc-1
- names:
  - ms-2
  - svc-2
```

I used Ansible for this. Below is my code shown via `cat test.yaml` & need help with Jinja2 Template:

```yaml
---
- name: Generate Conf file
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather list
    shell: "cat sample.csv"
    register: sample_list

  - name: Template
    ansible.builtin.template:
      src: test.j2
      dest: test.op
```

Comment: [How to create a minimal, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: We cannot guess the content of your template file nor the result you get from the above. Please make this a [mre]. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, that was my first post. Anyways, derived the solution from another similar post - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046613/i-need-to-generate-ansible-playbook-using-jinja2-with-csv-file-in-ansible?rq=2)

Answer (score 0):

Derived the solution from another similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046613/i-need-to-generate-ansible-playbook-using-jinja2-with-csv-file-in-ansible?rq=2).

**Playbook `myansible.yaml`**

```yaml
---
- name: Generate output.yaml
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: read csv
    read_csv:
      path: sample.csv
      delimiter: ','
    register: csvfile

  - name: generate template
    ansible.builtin.template:
      src: test.j2
      dest: output.yaml
```

**Template `test.j2`**

```yaml
{% for item in (csvfile.list | sort(attribute='ms')) %}
        - names:
          - {{ item.ms }}
          - {{ item.svc }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Input `sample.csv`**

```
ms,svc
ms-1,svc-1
ms-2,svc-2
```

**Outfile `output.yaml`**

```yaml
- names:
  - ms-1
  - svc-1
- names:
  - ms-2
  - svc-2
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The below declaration

```yaml
  result: "{{ sample_list.stdout_lines|
              map('split', ',')|
              map('community.general.dict_kv', 'names') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  result:
  - names:
    - ms-1
    - svc-1
  - names:
    - ms-2
    - svc-2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    result: "{{ sample_list.stdout_lines|
                map('split', ',')|
                map('community.general.dict_kv', 'names') }}"

  tasks:

    - command: cat sample.csv
      register: sample_list

    - debug:
        var: result
```